# how to set orientation in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios5

in iOS4.3 we did it like this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:***];
```

but now, xCode tells, that method `setOrientation` is undeclared for `UIDevice`
Basically, *I need to present UIImagePickerController in landscape orientation*. All my application is in landscape orientation. **How can I do this?**

---

I know, there is a great number of similar questions, but all of them is about iOS4. It doesnt work now...

```
UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate=self;
picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{
}];
```

Comment: Hello please check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594111/forcing-orientation-change

Comment: may be I can choose pictures from library without imagepicker?