# How can i change portrait to landscape and back by pressing a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an ipad app which i locked to landscape left. However it has an uiwebview which can change to portrait or landscape depending on the content. I want to do that pressing on a button. Is that possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a button that makes the user rotate the iPad?

Comment: Yes it is possible. That is the short answer.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594111/forcing-orientation-change

Answer (score 0):

In general, a UIViewController will allow its UIView to rotate to follow the orientation of the device.  If you don't want a rotation to occur, then you would specify your preferred/only orientation using `supportedInterfaceOrientations:`

So, for your need, when a button is pressed invoke `supportedInterfaceOrientations:` with the one and only orientation that the UIView should use.  After you specified the orientation call `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` to force the transition.

Comment: Does invoking `supportedInterfaceOrientations:` really help or change anything? Shouldn't it be called by system?

Comment: It doesn't cause a rotation to occur; it changes the allowed orientations.  When you call `attemptRotation...`, then the rotation occurs.

Comment: I think you don't need to call `supportedInterfaceOrientations:` method yourself, since no one is using the returned value. System should call this method for the returned value to take effect, and that's what `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` tries to do by asking the system to call that method.

Comment: The system uses the value returned by `supportedInterfaceOrientations` during the transition instigated by `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation`

Comment: Yes, this is true, but no one uses the value returned by a user call to `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. This is the point.